# Pandas merge is an order of magnitude slower than map for joining a Series to a DataFrame on a column

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, merge

Summary of situation:

We have some large `DataFrame` and a `Series` with some additional data corresponding to particular groups in the `DataFrame` (for example, from some supplementary data source, the result of a `groupby` or just from some other computation regarding the groups). To make a toy example, here we have 5000 different groups and 1e6 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"group": [i for i in range(5000)]*200, "value": np.random.random(int(1e6))})
grp_data = pd.DataFrame({"group":[i for i in range(5000)], "grp_value":np.random.random(5000)})
```

```
df
        group     value
0           0  0.760855
1           1  0.811482
2           2  0.115438
3           3  0.766736
4           4  0.651614
...       ...       ...
999995   4995  0.679567
999996   4996  0.016641
999997   4997  0.159281
999998   4998  0.762351
999999   4999  0.352805

[1000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

```
grp_data
      group  grp_value
0         0   0.628370
1         1   0.457861
2         2   0.954026
3         3   0.509669
4         4   0.297275
...     ...        ...
4995   4995   0.415900
4996   4996   0.511556
4997   4997   0.698350
4998   4998   0.905850
4999   4999   0.197737

[5000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Here are two methods for joining on the extra group data, one using `merge` and the other using `map`.

```
tic = time.perf_counter()
merge_df = df.merge(grp_data, on="group", how="left")
print(time.perf_counter() - tic)
```

```
96.42482600065705 milliseconds
```

```
tic = time.perf_counter()
map_df = df
map_df["grp_value"] = map_df.group.map(grp_data.set_index("group").grp_value)
print(str((time.perf_counter() - tic)*1000) + " milliseconds")
```

```
14.693562000502425 milliseconds
```

Each produce the same DataFrame as desired with the `grp_value`'s paired with their corresponding `group` for each row:

```
        group     value  grp_value
0           0  0.760855   0.628370
1           1  0.811482   0.457861
2           2  0.115438   0.954026
3           3  0.766736   0.509669
4           4  0.651614   0.297275
...       ...       ...        ...
999995   4995  0.679567   0.415900
999996   4996  0.016641   0.511556
999997   4997  0.159281   0.698350
999998   4998  0.762351   0.905850
999999   4999  0.352805   0.197737

[1000000 rows x 3 columns]
```

But map is an order of magnitude faster for the same operation.

With the actual DataFrame that I found this difference (which has more columns and is longer), the performance difference was even worse at 15x slower. From what I've read online, I only ever see merge suggested for this kind of thing and I find myself doing this kind of operation a lot. My question is twofold:

1. What is the natural way to combine data in the way described above using pandas?
2. Why is merge so much slower than map in this case?

Comment: map when you have only 1 column that you want to add

Comment: merge when you have more than 1... 
et voila :)